# Longest remaining sub string only with vowel

Tags: string, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a string containing only lower alphabets, you can remove any number of sub-string from given string but same substring can be removed at most twice such that remaining string should contains only vowel(s). Find longest remaining sub-string with only vowels. If not possible the return -1.

I think this can be solved by DP. but I am not able to form recursive solution

eg: aabbeeddii 
o/p: aaeeii

eg: aabbibbibbe
o/p: aaie

Comment: By "alphabets" I assume you mean "letters". Does "remove any substring" mean it has to be the same substring both times?

Comment: yes only small letters. And you can remove any substring.But if you are can not remove same sub-string more than two times.

Comment: eg: aabbibbibbe -> Here bb is present three times so you can not make longest string aaiie. As you have to remove bb three times. Instead you can remove bbibb and bb to form aaie

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Your question makes it seem like you can only remove two substrings, or one substring twice; is that correct, or can you remove as many substrings as you like so long as each substring isn't removed more than twice? Please edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: you can remove any number of substring of any size. But same substring can be removed at most twice. You can remove vowels and consonants both. Edited the question